# How to filter strings for SteamIDs

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have strings like that:

```
# 9034 2 "WOOLE" STEAM_1:0:186073148 00:28 56 0 active 196608
# 9025 3 "Yeah" STEAM_0:0:544561822 01:57 51 0 active 786432
# 9035 4 "Tarkion" STEAM_1:0:201330027 00:27 53 65 active 196608
# 8986 5 "SADOMAZO" STEAM_1:1:511042392 23:53 185 0 active 196608
```

and I need to filter out the steamids f.e "STEAM_1:0:186073148" to create an arrays with the ids.

What's the best way in JavaScript for me to implement? I thought about RegEx but I have nearly zero experience with it.

Would be awesome if somebody could help me <3

Best regards

Comment: Some of the questions - 1. Are these separate 4 strings or a single string, 2. Do you want an exact match using `STEAM_1:0:186073148` or any string containing `STEAM` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have your strings as an Array `stringsArray`:

```
const stringsArray = ['# 9034 2 "WOOLE" STEAM_1:0:186073148 00:28 56 0 active 196608',
'# 9025 3 "Yeah" STEAM_0:0:544561822 01:57 51 0 active 786432',
'# 9035 4 "Tarkion" STEAM_1:0:201330027 00:27 53 65 active 196608',
'# 8986 5 "SADOMAZO" STEAM_1:1:511042392 23:53 185 0 active 196608']
```

You could then do the following to get an array of your steamIDs:

```
function getSteamIDs(stringsArray) {
  const steamIDs = []
  stringsArray.forEach(function (element) {
    const elementID = element.match(/STEAM_\d:\d:\d{9}/)[0]
    if(elementID && steamIDs.indexOf(elementID) < 0 ) steamIDs.push(elementID)
  })

  return steamIDs
}

console.log(getSteamIDs(stringsArray))
```

Comment: @L4rs I've edited my answer for the update of your question. You should be able to also filter for IDs starting with STEAM_0. Also, I wrapped everything in a function.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I edited a steamid to STEAM_0 because both ways are possible and my first version contained only STEAM_1's.